# BootstrapValidator validate multiple text field with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator

I am stuck at here, i'm trying to validate multiple textfield with same name, but it validates only the first input text and the rest nothing shows.

```
<form id = "frm_org_id">
<input type="text" name="email_address[]" placeholder="Email address" class="email_address">
<input type="text" name="email_address[]" placeholder="Email address" class="email_address">
<input type="text" name="email_address[]" placeholder="Email address" class="email_address">
<input type="text" name="email_address[]" placeholder="Email address" class="email_address">
</form>
```

js

```
$('#frm_org_id').bootstrapValidator({

    fields:{
        'email_address[]':{
            validators:{
                notEmpty:{
                    message: ' required'
                },
                emailAddress:{
                    message: 'Invalid email address'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How do i validate independently each of the field when typing?

Answer (score 0):

You should put input tag in div with class="form-group".
t.e.:

```
<form id = "frm_org_id">
 <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="email_address[]" placeholder="Email address" class="email_address">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="email_address[]" placeholder="Email address" class="email_address">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="email_address[]" placeholder="Email address" class="email_address">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="email_address[]" placeholder="Email address" class="email_address">
  </div>
</form>
```

for working example see :
https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/demo/multiple.html